# Is there a name for this "euclidean" set of real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, euclidean-geometry

Let $E$ be the smallest set of real numbers such that:

(1) $1\in E$,

(2) $x \in E \implies x/n\in E$  $\;$($n=1,2, \;...\;$),

(3) $x,y \in E \implies |x-y| \in E$,

(4) $x,y \in E \implies \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \in E$.

The idea is that $E$ is the set of distances generated by euclidean straight-edge and compass constructions from a unit segment.

Comment: The set of distances generated by euclidean straight-edge and compass constructions from a unit segment contains all rational numbers but the properties you gave do not imply that.

Comment: Corrected now (I hope!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of distances generated by Euclidean straight-edge and compass constructions from a unit segment is the same as the set of coordinates of  [constructible points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number). This is called the set of *constructible numbers*, as you expect.